# Creating a Server 2008 Image

Tags: windows-server-2008, images, disk-image

I have noticed lately that I have been repeating the same steps for setting up new dedicated servers for our clients, which involves probably 2-4 hours of configurations, software installs, etc.

The commonality is that they are all using Server 2008 R2, and all pretty much require the exact same software/configurations.

Is it possible to create some sort of Server 2008 Image I can pack into an .iso and use for new installations rather than doing all of these things over and over again? I have tried Google searching for it in the past, but really never come up with any information on doing what I need to do.

Comment: I opted to go with Clonezilla, as it is Free/Open-Source, but thank you all for the great suggestions!

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works like any other OS (which it should) I believe doing sysprep in the command line and then using software like:

[Acronis](http://www.acronis.com/)

[Ghost](http://us.norton.com/ghost/)

You can make an image file of your drive.  The reason you do sysprep first is to get rid of any unique items created when Windows is installed on a computer that if you try to image ontop of another computer, will end up causing all kinds of problems.  Hope this helps!

Comment: You beat me to suggesting Acronis. +1!

Comment: Been using it religiously since January, love it.  In fact, using it right now to recover someone's drive.

Answer (score 1):

We use Symantec System Recovery to create images much like Acronis.  The image can be converted directly to a VM which is nice and you can restore to different hardware which has saved us a great deal of time if a system fails or we are moving to newer hardware.  The application will indicate what drivers are needed for the new hardware.[Symantec System Recovery](http://www.symantec.com/business/products/family.jsp?familyid=backupexec)  There is a 60 day free trial.